# ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: message authentication code incorrect

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, sftp

Since a few days I'm facing an issue while being connected to my server in ssh, for proxy/tunel usage.

## I - Setup

### Client

Here is the machine :

> **iMac:~ Luca$ sw_vers**
>
> ProductName:  Mac OS X
>
> ProductVersion:   10.11.6
>
> BuildVersion: 15G1108
>
> **iMac:~ Luca$ sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding**
>
> net.inet.ip.forwarding: 0
>
> **iMac:~ Luca$ sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.fw.enable**
>
> net.inet.ip.fw.enable: 1

Tried on three different network.

### Browser

I'm using Firefox 50.0.1 to browse internet, with the FoxyProxy extension configured like so :

> host address : 127.0.0.1
>
> port : 9999
>
> socks v5

### SSH command

I'm using Terminal.app to connect in ssh to my server.

> **iMac:~ Luca$ ssh -p 53 -D 9999 luca@myIP**

### Server

> **luca@myServer:~$ ssh -V**
>
> OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
>
> **luca@myServer:~$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward**
>
> 1

## II - Expected

Once the connection is open, I can browse any website without any issue (with my IP being my server one).

This was fine until a few days.
This is still fine if I try :

- same server (A), another computer (Y)
- same computer (X), another server (B)

*From what it looks like, it doesn't work with my computer (X) and my server (A).*

## III - What happens

> luca@myServer:~$ ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to myIP: message authentication code incorrect

The connection is then closed.

This message appears at random time. But I can reproduce it easily with a big data load through the proxy : load multiple videos, download big files, etc...

## IV - Another way, similar problem

If I connect to my server through sftp:// (with FileZilla) with the same login (luca) and same port (53). Then I try to download a file, every <30 seconds I get the following error :

> Error : Incorrect MAC received on packet

Once again, this happen only with my computer (X) and my server (A).
If I try another server (B) on the same computer (X) : no problem.
If I try the same server (A) on another computer (Y) : no problem.

## V - What I've tried (and didn't fix)

1. Reboot the server and the computer
2. Restart ssh/sshd on both the server and the computer
3. Delete the knowns_hosts file on the computer
4. Specify a `-m` and `-c` with the ssh command
5. Specify a `-o GSSAPIKeyExchange=no` within the ssh command
6. Uncomment the Ciphers and/or MACs lines within `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on the server or/and the computer
7. Tried to look at `-vvvvv` option with the ssh command and read logs on server/computer, nothing looked related.

Any help would be appreciated.

## APPENDIX

### Server `ssh -Q mac`

> **luca@myServer:~$ ssh -Q mac**
>   hmac-sha1
>   hmac-sha1-96
>   hmac-sha2-256
>   hmac-sha2-512
>   hmac-md5
>   hmac-md5-96
>   hmac-ripemd160
>   hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com
>   umac-64@openssh.com
>   umac-128@openssh.com
>   hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
>   hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com
>   hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
>   hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
>   hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
>   hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com
>   hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com
>   umac-64-etm@openssh.com
>   umac-128-etm@openssh.com

### Computer `ssh -Q mac`

> **iMac:~ Luca$ ssh -Q mac**
>   hmac-sha1
>   hmac-sha1-96
>   hmac-sha2-256
>   hmac-sha2-512
>   hmac-md5
>   hmac-md5-96
>   hmac-ripemd160
>   hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com
>   umac-64@openssh.com
>   umac-128@openssh.com
>   hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
>   hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com
>   hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
>   hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
>   hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
>   hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com
>   hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com
>   umac-64-etm@openssh.com
>   umac-128-etm@openssh.com

### Server `ssh -v -p 53 -D 9999 luca@myIP`

```
iMac:~ Luca$ ssh -v -p 53 -D 9999 luca@myIP

OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to myIP [myIP] port 53.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Luca/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Luca/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Luca/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Luca/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Luca/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Luca/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Luca/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Luca/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to myIP:53 as 'luca'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:DUAAYL1r0QUDtRI89JozTTz+bm5wcg4cOSaFaRdbr/Y
debug1: Host '[myIP]:53' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/Luca/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Luca/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Luca/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Luca/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Luca/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password

luca@myIP's password:

debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to myIP ([myIP]:53).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:9999 forwarded to remote address socks:0
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 9999.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 9999.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: channel 2: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = fr_FR.UTF-8
Debian GNU/Linux 8.6

Linux <server> #1 SMP Tue Mar 18 14:48:24 CET 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux

server    : 274305
hostname  : myServer
eth0 IPv4 : myIPv4
eth0 IPv6 : myIPv6
Last login: Thu Dec  8 15:36:09 2016 from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

luca@myServer:~$
```

### Error I see sometime

> luca@myServer:~$ Bad packet length 3045540078.
>
> padding error: need -1249427218 block 8 mod 6
>
> ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 5.39.88.21: message authentication code incorrect

### Server `ssh -o macs=hmac-sha1 -v -p 53 -D 9999 luca@myServer` when crash happens

```
iMac:~ Luca$ ssh -o macs=hmac-sha1 -v -p 53 -D 9999 luca@myIP
// [...]
luca@myServer:~$ debug1: Connection to port 9999 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 9999 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 4: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 9999 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 5: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 9999 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 6: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 9999 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 7: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 9999 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 8: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 9999 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 9: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 9999 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 10: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 9999 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 11: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 9999 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 12: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 9999 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 13: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 9999 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 14: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 9999 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 15: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 9999 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 16: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 9999 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 17: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 9999 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 18: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 9999 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 19: new [dynamic-tcpip]
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to myIP : message authentication code incorrect
iMac:~ Luca$
```

### After updating SSH on client-side

```
iMac:~ Luca$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016

iMac:~ Luca$ ssh -p 53 -D 9999 luca@myIP
luca@myIP's password: 
luca@ns3274305:~$ ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to myIP port 53: message authentication code incorrect

iMac:~ Luca$ ssh -o macs=hmac-sha1 -p 53 -D 9999 luca@myIP
luca@myIP's password: 
luca@ns3274305:~$ ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to myIP port 53: message authentication code incorrect
iMac:~ Luca$
```

Comment: What MAC is used in the connections that are failing? You will find it in the verbose log of `ssh` or `sftp` (`-v` switch). If you don't know where, post the whole log.

Comment: Hello @Jakuje , I've edited my question with an appendix including the `ssh -v`. Please let me know if you see anything.

Comment: hmm. You are using `chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com` with implicit MAC. I never had a problem with this one. You can try explicit `ssh -o macs=hmac-sha1 server`, if you will see any difference. The issue might be also related to rekeying (you would see some debug messages before crashing the connection), which could be solved by update of your ssh client and server (current is 7.3).

Comment: @Jakuje I already tried the `-m` option with several MACs. The error is still present with `-o macs=hmac-sha1`. I've added the log before the crash happens, but doesn't seems relevant to me.

Comment: Does the same happen when you don't use the `socks` proxy and just transfer the data there? The error is coming from low level packet handling and therefore it is pretty hard to debug.

Comment: I've update my computer to `OpenSSH_7.3p1` but error is still present (see my last edit). Problems happens randomly at times, and 100% reproductible immediately when having an heavy load transfert (through socks or sftp). I can try to update ssh on server-side, but that would not explain why it is working on other computers.

Comment: @Jakuje For information, it's working on another computer with the same configuration I had previously `OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8` (pointing to the same user:server). Can't figure what's wrong here...

Comment: It might even be some kind of IDS on the way (in your or the server network), which is mangling with the packets.

Comment: @Jakuje With the computer which is having the issue I've tried on several internet connections (home, office, 4G). Either in ethernet or wifi. Other computer I've ssh on with the same command (without the issue) are on those networks too. Could it be the network card itself ?

Comment: On my Jolla smartphone with Sailfish OS, I solved this problem by adding the line `Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com` to the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (from this answer: https://together.jolla.com/question/208462/ssh-stopped-working/?answer=208470#post-id-208470).

Comment: Re: "Problems happens randomly at times, and 100% reproductible immediately when having an heavy load ..." Using a less computationally intensive MAC, like `umac-64-etm@openssh.com` helped me in my scenario (https://dentarg.blog/post/186913288147/umac-64-etm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated from Mac OS El Capitan (10.11) to Mac OS Sierra (10.12).

The problem doesn't occur anymore.

*I still don't know what the problem really was.*

Comment: I'm on 10.12.4 and still experience this problem.

Comment: 10.14 has this problem.

Comment: 10.14.6 had this problem so I upgraded to 10.15.5 and still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem to go away by disabling AVB/EAV mode on the advanced settings for the Ethernet adapter on the Mac (under Big Sur).

Comment: This solution actually worked for me. Turns out it simply wasn't supported by my ethernet adapter.